# Automatically add Todo for missing reference

Tags: cross-referencing, todonotes

I'm looking for a way to add todo notes in addition to the two questionmarks wherever a \ref is undefined/missing.

Currently I'm writing a \todo manually for any \ref that I intend to fulfill later. Figures for example where I don't have the actual image yet. I would like to see this done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch the `\@setref` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@setref}{\ifx#1\relax}{\ifx#1\relax \todo{MISSING REFERENCE}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a missing reference: \ref{somefig}.
\end{document}
```

May not work with every package that does something with the ref mechanism.

**Update:**

For `\autoref` in the `hyperref` package, add (also between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`):

```
\ifdefined\HyRef@autosetref \patchcmd{\HyRef@autosetref}
      {\else}{\else\todo{MISSING REFERENCE}}{}{}\fi
```

Comment: Thanks... umh, you don't know by chance how to do this with \autoref from the hyperref package, do you?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: **Please Note**: As these solutions hack into the internals, they may someday break if the internals are significantly changed.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks. However since this is a one time solution for my master thesis I suppose (i.e. hope) it will break long after I have handed it in.